# How to get string, wich is after a certain string in a text

Tags: c#, string, filtering

Am looking to get a certain part of a textfile, wich changes with each file, the very part infront of it doesnt however, and it only occurs once in the whole file (in this case it's a HTML file and im writing a simple automation program, wich gets that text (and some other variables) and stores them into a .csv).

Was searching all day for an Answer, sadly didn't find anything useful. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: And what is your attempt? Did you try anything yourself? Sounds like a task that I can assign to a student in the second week

Comment: `string result = text.Substring(text.IndexOf(stringYoureLookingFor) + stringYoureLookingFor.Length);`